# Move Controls and Graphics

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a twincat device and Windows Ce 6 device.
I am listining a twincat for get data from machine.
After get data I am making graphicals process.moving picture box,drawing image,changing images
so my program is very slow I can not catch real time datas.
What Can I do?
Do I have to use Usercontrol for different image process or Thread?
Thanks a lot

There is a Property in Form1

```
Bitmap MyImage
{

  get
  {
//  A Lot of difficult process Drawing Image
   return Im;
  }

}
```

When I call this property from Thread.Which thread is make this process Form thread or MyThread ?

Comment: `UserControl` won't help you , go for threads !

Comment: @Mehran Can you some explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without using Threads you'll face the same problem with `UserControls` , It's recommended to separate `UI` tasks from other stuff that you're working with It means that if your program is too slow for getting data in real-time you can use two threads , one for getting data and the other for drawing and doing other stuff with `UI` in this way `UI` thread won't affect the data thread but remember you may need to optimize your drawing stuff as well by using some Image Processing Libraries or even using faster technologies designed for Working with Graphics like `WPF`

here's a very good tutorial for getting started with Threads in C# :

[Multithreaded Programming Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083/Multithreaded-Programming-Using-C)

please keep in mind if you provide us more details and codes we can help you even more :)

Comment: @Mahran
Thanks for your answer but I have more questions :)
There is a Property in Form1

'Bitmap MyImage
{

  get
  {
//  A Lot of difficult process Drawing Image

  }

}'

When I call this property from Thread.Which thread is make this process Form thread or MyThread ?

Comment: you're welcome , It's running on the thread which has called it , if you have called this property from the UI thread It's gonna run on the UI thread , please be aware of cross thread and thread-safe too , sometimes calling functions or properties from different threads may cause cross thread which results the program to crash !